# How to hide JSON data being sent back from the server

Tags: json, browser, hide, httprequest

I have an app that received JSON data from the server. Currently when I look at firebug, I can see all the data that is being transmitted.

Since its possible for anyone to view and steal this data, what steps do I need to take so that my data is only viewed from within my app and cannot be viewed otherwise.

What are some keywords I can google to understand how this is done and what technologies I need to use.

Thanks

Comment: Encrypt the data, or the whole JSON string? But what kind of app is it? If it is written in Javascript, then the most you can do is obfuscate the JS code, but it will be cracked by determined person anyway.

Comment: Its a rails app. Ive seen other websites where if you look at them through Firebug you cannot see the data load. Somehow it only appears in the browser. How do they do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've missed the point.  You've sent the data to the web client, which in this case happens to Firefox.  Once you've sent the data it is out of your hands.

Firefox can then do anything it want with the data including rendering it on the screen (which is what you want) and rendering it to any debug listeners (which is what you don't want).

Even if there were some way to block Firefox from displaying the data in firebug, its easy for anyone to write their own web client that pretends to be a web browser and then they can do whatever they want with the data.

You can't have it both ways - showing them the data on the screen but at the same time hiding the raw json that you have sent to their browser.

If application is sending json data that the user should not see, some kind of secure data, and that information is not shown to the user in their browser, then don't send that data in json.  If they are allowed to view it in their browser then you must send it to their browser, and they can read it in any way they want to.

Comment: I'm thinking that even sending some sort of data which has to be secure from the authenticated user is going to be problematic.

Comment: Just to add to the point: It is possible to intercept any communication coming in and out of your device (laptop, computer and even iPhone), so any data at transport level should be considered visible. The point is how hard it is to actually get sensible data out of it. For example, in case the data is encrypted, the decryption method is closed source or you don't have the key to decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

One method i always use to is to encypt the data, especially if it is a password, you can use blowfish encryption, this is noe of thhe most secured encryption method. sin bcrypt(), with a strong salt. check more here  php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php